# how to calculate jaccard similarity distance between two list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have input like below:

```py
list1 = [['Search','engines','using','machine','learning','pattern','detections'],['machine','learning','helped','Google','automatically','sift','pages']]

list2 = ['Machine','learning','ever','evolving','technology']
```

I have tried below code:

```py
def jaccard_similarity(list1, list2):
    intersection = len(list(set(list1).intersection(list2)))
    print(list(set(list1).intersection(list2)))
    union = (len(list1) + len(list2)) - intersection
    return float(intersection / union)

jaccard_similarity(input_list,input_list1)
```

getting below error:

```sh
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: You cannot create a set out of a list of lists i.e. `list1` Also what's the expected output, a list of floats?

Comment: expected output should be list of floats.

Comment: Is the expected output `[0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666]` in this example?

Comment: yes. perfect . like this

Comment: I have added the answer, please take a look @Praveenkumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I believe you're looking to do is get the `jaccard_similarity` for each list in `list1`. If so, just loop through them. Also, made small corrections to the lines in `jaccard_similarity`.

```
list1=[
    ['Search','engines','using','machine','learning','pattern','detections'], 
    ['machine','learning','helped','Google','automatically','sift','pages']
]
list2 = ['Machine','learning','ever','evolving','technology']

def jaccard_similarity(list1, list2):
    intersection = len(set(list1).intersection(list2)) #no need to call list here
    union = len(list1 + list2) - intersection #you only need to call len once here
    return intersection / union #also no need to cast to float as this will be done for you

for l in list1:
    print(jaccard_similarity(l, list2))
```

Or in a comprehension

```
similarities = [jaccard_similarity(l, list2) for l in list1]
```

**Edit** Here's a much simpler way to get the `jaccard_similarity` btw:

```
def jaccard_similarity(list1, list2):
    s1, s2 = set(list1), set(list2)
    return len(s1 & s2) / len(s1 | s2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the Jaccard Index between two lists using your function:

```py
jaccard_similarity(list1[0], list2)
```

returns:

```sh
['learning']
Out[7]: 0.09090909090909091
```

You could also use a loop to apply your function to the different sublists in list1 and get the Jaccard Index between the sublists of list1 and list2.